# user input string and int, if statements

Tags: java, string, if-statement, int

I'm new to java and I'm working on some homework.
I am trying to write an 'If' statement, by with a string and int. 
What is supposed to happen is the user inputs gender, today's date, and their birthday.
Then the program is supposed to tell you if you're a male and you're a certain age, the best rate of you is...
But, what I'm having trouble is, how do I write an 'If' statement with int and a string?

the //comments were given by my professor

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Welcome to the car renter's rate finder.");       
System.out.print("Please enter the renter's gender (m/f): ");
String gender = kb.nextLine();

System.out.print("Please enter the today's date (mm dd yyyy): ");
     int curMonth = kb.nextInt();
     int curDay = kb.nextInt();
     int curYear = kb.nextInt();
     kb.nextLine();

System.out.print("Please enter the renter's date of birth (mm dd yyyy): ");
     int birthMonth = kb.nextInt();
     int birthDay = kb.nextInt();
     int birthYear = kb.nextInt();
     kb.nextLine();

     int age = 0;

     String rateResult;



  // Get age...
     age = calcAge(curMonth, curDay, curYear, birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);

  // Get the rental rate...
     //rateResult = calcRateClass(age, gender); 
  // Display the results...
     //displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);
     displayResults(age);
  }
}

private static int calcAge(int curMonth, int curDay, int curYear,int, birthMonth,int birthDay,int birthYear)
{
return curYear - birthYear;
}

private static void displayResults(int age)
{
System.out.printf("Thanks. \n");
System.out.printf("The driver is %d years old. \n",age);
if (age >= 35 && age <= 65)
//Best rate (male drivers, age 33 – 65 and female drivers, age 30 - 62) -- $40.00 per day, $200.00 per week
  {
  System.out.println("$40.00 per day, $200.00 per week.");
  }
```

Comment: `if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && (age >= 35 && age <= 65)) {...}`

Comment: @MadProgrammer: for the sake of readability: `if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && (35 <= age  && age <= 65)) {...}`

Comment: @MichaelLihs Personally, I like the way it reads now `>= && <=` visually shows a "between" intention, but that's me and I'm simple minded ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I agree - it's personal style :) in Maths you normally have a < x < b (which you can't have in Java), maybe that's why I like it more... but I see your point :)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you pass `gender` to your `displayResults` method

```
private static void displayResults(String gender, int age)
```

Then you can use `String#equals` to compare the value, but this is a case sensitive comparison, so something like `String#equalsIgnoreCase` would be a better choice

Once you have that information, you can include `gender` in your `if` statement

You could use...

```
if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") {
    if (age >= 35 && age <= 65) {
```

This is good if you want to do more then one thing with "M", like if their aged over `65` for example.

If you're only going to do a single action against "M", you could use something like

```
if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && (age >= 35 && age <= 65)) {...}
```

which can reduce the "pyramid of doom" indent issue

I would suggest having a look at [The Strings trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) and [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

To implement this in single if statement

> //Best rate (male drivers, age 33 – 65 and female drivers, age 30 -
>   62) -- $40.00 per day, $200.00 per week

You could use this if:

```
if( (gender.equalsIgnoreCase('m') && (age >= 33 && age <= 65)) || (gender.equalsIgnoreCase('f') && (age >= 30 && age <=62)) )
```

And of course you need to pass gender parametr to your displayResults function:

```
private static void displayResults(String gender, int age)
```